# White space in book document class for figure

Tags: spacing, graphics

Using,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
```

but getting lot of white space between two images. 
I am in need of some global command to reduce this space because I am getting such a problem in many places in my report.

So global command will help me lot. My MWE is:

```
 \documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
    \usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc} 
    \begin{document}
    \chapter{Characterization of IPECs and discussion}
    \FloatBarrier
    \section{Phase diagram}

The samples of the HMPAA/PEI2 and the PEG-b-HMPAA/PEI2 at pH 5 shows the same phase behavior like the HMPAA/PEI1 and the PEG-b-HMPAA/PEI1 at pH 7. On day 01, HMPAA/PEI2 at pH 5 forms precipitate from charge ratios 0.4 to 1.0 and after 15 days it extends from 0.4 to 1.3. For the PEG-b-HMPAA/PEI2 series at pH 5, it forms precipitate from charge ratios 0.5 to 1.0 on day 01 and after 15 days it extends from 0.5 to 1.3. The precipitated samples are shown in figure \ref{fig.731} with gray background. The phase diagrams are shown in figure \ref{fig.745}.



    \begin{figure}[htbp!]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{..//Images/CMTP10.pdf}
    \caption{PEG-b-HMPAA/PEI2 - 01 day - 25 $^{\circ}$C, pH 5 and concentration 0.4 mmol/L.}
    \label{fig.731}
    \end{figure}


    \begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering
    \subfloat[For HMPAA/PEI2 - pH 5]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{..//Images/rephd09.pdf}\label{fig.745a}}
    \subfloat[For PEG-b-HMPAA/PEI2 - pH 5]{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{..//Images/rephd10.pdf}\label{fig.745b}}
    \caption{Phase diagram from day 01 to 15 for different charge ratio at 25 $^{\circ}$C, pH 5 and concentration 0.4 mmol/L.}\label{fig.745}
    \end{figure}

In general, the turbidity of the complex depends on polycation in all the cases. The trend of complex formed by PEI1 and PEI2 are almost at respective pH. The complex without PEG shows higher turbidity than the complex formed with PEG. This might have happened due to close packing or close interaction of polycation with polyanion without PEG. At pH5, the complex with PEI1 and PEI2 are almost having same phase diagram at same concentration. 

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

The image of the book is given below.

[image]

Comment: a `MWE` would be needed.

Comment: @Denis I wouldn't have removed the spacing tag (it is unlikely to be related to graphics)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle OK with me. I put it back.

Comment: At least we would need to see your code specific to those figures and what you're doing to flush them both on the same page. Are you using `\afterpage{\clearpage}`? What about possible settings of `\topfraction` and/or `\bottomfraction`?

Comment: Did you try with the `\raggedbottom` directive?

Comment: No i didnt try \raggedbottom. How to use it? Is it global command?

Comment: Yes. In your preamble. The default is  `\flushbottom, so that all pages end at exactly the same point (vertically).

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn’t very clear, and your code doesn’t compile, but if I understand correctly, you want to change (globally) the value of the `\@fpsep` parameter.  For example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{mwe} % just for generating this Minimal Working Example

% The patch that *might* solve your problem:
\makeatletter
    \setlength{\@fpsep}{24pt} % adjust value as you need
\makeatother



\begin{document}

\chapter{Characterization of IPECs and discussion}

\lipsum[1]

% \FloatBarrier % irrelevant for this MWE

\section{Phase diagram}

\lipsum[2]

\begin{figure}[htbp!] % "htbp!"???
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{image}
    \caption{First image}
    \label{fig.731}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[!htbp] % as above: ???
    \centering
    \subfloat[For HMPAA/PEI2 - pH 5]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{image-a}
        \label{fig.745a}
    }
    \subfloat[For PEG-b-HMPAA/PEI2 - pH 5]{
        \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{image-b}
        \label{fig.745b}
    }
    \caption{Phase diagram from etc.}
    \label{fig.745}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3-4]

\end{document}
```

I wouldn’t do so, anyway, since, IMHO, the preset value makes the output look much better.